# Backbone + Marionette Additional Models Loading

Tags: backbone.js, pagination, marionette

I'm building an "app" (more of a website, but anyway), which has a list of posts (a `Marionettte.CompositeView` populated with `Marionette.ItemView`s. Below those posts is a "Load more" button, which triggers a pagination-route (`/posts/P:offset`, so `/posts/P10` for example). When clicked, It's easy enough to load `/api/posts/P10`, add those to the collection and have them appended, that's a piece of cake. What I can't get my head around, is when someone lands on the url `/posts/P10` cold, how do I make that page show the first 10 posts, plus the extra ones that should be triggered by the pagination-segment?

Answer (score 0):

`currentPage` property of your `Paginator` stores the most recent page number. If it's not `9` - you have to load all 10 pages. And you can do it by changing `perPage` property -

`this.perPage = this.perPage * pageNumberYouWant // 10`

Then revert `perPage` value to original one after the request.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your life easier by making the url more generic `/posts/P:offset?count=count` and have your server set the default count to 10.

So:

`/posts/P0` will show you Items from 0 to 10

`/posts/P0?count=20` will show you Items from 0 to 20

`/posts/P10` will show you Items from 10 to 20